# batch file changing double quote

Tags: batch-file

Having trouble running a batch file.

```
SET startIN="D:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Desktop\DataXfer Helper\StartFolder"
SET collection="D:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Desktop\DataXfer Helper\StartFolder\*.zip"

FOR /F %%G IN (‘dir /b %collection%\*.zip’) DO  “C:\Program Files\Winzip\wzunzip” –E  %startIN%\%%G  %startIN%
```

When I type the line at the command prompt - it works fine (the only difference is when typed at the command prompt I use `%G` instead of `%%G`).

So, the environement variables are being created properly - but when I run the batch, the single quotes and the hyphen before the E are being turned into other characters (can't identify what they are).

So, any ideas why running the batch would change the characters?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems:

1. The symbols in your `FOR` line are not supported ASCII chars. Retype the `'`, `"`, and `-` in the command line to correct them.
2. The string expansion is going to include the quotes you set in the path above. For example, `%startIN%\%%G` will expand to `"D:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Desktop\DataXfer Helper\StartFolder"\MyFile.zip`. When dealing with paths, make sure your logic is aware of quotes so they don't get trapped in the middle of the result.

Try updating your script to this:

```
REM Remove the quotes from the path.
REM Quotes will be added once we know the full path.
SET startIN=D:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Desktop\DataXfer Helper\StartFolder

REM Quote here because we know the full path.
SET collection="%startIN%\*.zip"

REM Update FOR loop to include parsing options and properly quote output.
REM Also update invalid ASCII chars.
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%G IN (`dir /b %collection%`) DO "C:\Program Files\Winzip\wzunzip" -E "%startIN%\%%G" "%startIN%"
```

Comment: That was exactly what was needed - ran perfectly with that change.  Thank you very much :)